# Forwarding Set-Cookie header via Grafana auth proxy to the browser

Tags: authentication, cookies, grafana, traefik-middleware

I'm using [Grafana auth proxy](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/auth-proxy/) with [Traefik forwardAuth middleware](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/forwardauth/) to secure my dashboards. We store access and refresh tokens as server-side http-only cookies. These get forwarded to my auth service which verifies the access token or returns a new one if expired and refresh token is valid.

I can access Grafana fine until the access token expires. When this happens, I'd need to use refresh token to issue a new access token. The token (in a cookie) gets forwarded to my auth service, where I can issue a new access token. Then I add the `Set-Cookie` header to set the new token, but these headers are not forwarded to the Grafana frontend.

I was inspecting the Grafana proxy auth config where `headers` property seemed promising, but as far as I can tell from quick inspection of it's source code it actually only remaps headers to one of the predefined attributes, and it doesn't forward anything to the client.

Is there a way to somehow forward the `Set-Cookie` headers via Grafana auth proxy to the browser or am I stuck?

Comment: In the end we figured it's not possible to do it and decided on a different approach.